# Set sunday as first day of the week in Unity calendar

Tags: unity, calendar

For the moment Monday is displayed in my calendar. I want to change it to Sunday. Can you tell me where can I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
$ sudo sed 's/first_weekday .*/first_weekday 1/' -i /usr/share/i18n/locales/${LANG%.UTF-8}
$ sudo locale-gen
$ killall unity-panel-service
```

Restart computer.